# Possible to prevent multitail from closing "finished" command windows?

Tags: command-line, tail, multitail

Assume a multitail call like the following:

```
multitail -s 2 -l "long-running-command" -l "short-running-command"
```

Now, I would like to have both windows remain open, even after they are finished. However, multitail will just close the "short-running-command"-window once it exits. Which makes it kinda useless for my use case.

I know there are workarounds like outputting to files and tailing those instead, but I wonder if there is a way to keep the windows open in multitail even after the process is finished, without creating new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches I can think of.

First, if you don't mind having `multitail` close when the longer running command finishes, you can pipe the shorter running command to it and display `stdin`:

```
short-running-command | multitail -s 2 -l "long-running-command" -j
```

Second, you can add a long delay after running the commands:

```
multitail -s 2 -l "long-running-command; sleep 120" -l "short-running-command; sleep 3600"
```

Comment: The first one won't do it for me, but the second one is a nice idea.